# IgnoreRoute for PHP Site embedded in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-3, ignoreroute

I have an MVC 3 site with an embedded worpress blog.  All the following urls are directed through MVC.

```
www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com/aboutus
www.mysite.com/contactus
```

I also have a top level directory called Blog, which is a php wordpress blog.  If I access `www.mysite.com/blog/index.php` the blog shows up.  But all access to `www.mysite.com/blog` seems to get routed through MVC and produces what seems to be an unrelated error referring to `System.Web.Helpers` being missing (I deployed it to the bin folder so I know that is not the issue).

In the `RegisterRoutes` method of my `Global.asax.cs` file I have tried both of these lines at the top of the method, but neither seem to work.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Blog");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathinfo}", new { folder = "Blog" });
```

Anyone have an idea?

I have included the contents of the Global.asax.cs as per Snoopy's request:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Blog");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathinfo}", new { folder = "Blog" });
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your complete RegisterRoutes please.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to ignore routing for the folder "Blog".

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("Blog/{*pathInfo}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Routes.IgnoreRoute("Blog/");` Also remember to put it first in the routing table.

It's probably about the missing `/` at the end