# Integrating PHP pages into ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I have project in .net mvc3 .I want to integrating PHP pages into .NET MVC 3
      And Deploy?

Comment: Could you show what you tried?

Comment: We try to run .php web pages as view using .net with mvc.

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/t/1177844.aspx?MVC+asp+net+app+with+subdirectory+running+a+php+app+causes+performance+problems+for+php+

Comment: The solution in your link should work. Just put your php page in a separate directory and make sure the routing ignores it.

Comment: Can you explain with an example or any link?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the php page in a subdirectory like www.mypage.com/php. Then change the routing so that your subdirectory is ignored. See this question for details:
[IgnoreRoute for PHP Site embedded in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777417/ignoreroute-for-php-site-embedded-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: This seems to be a separate issue with your .Net configuration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura

Comment: Or try this: http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2007/01/12/iis7-http-error-4043-not-found-for-php-cfm-etc/

Comment: This Solved But Now New Issue given below

Comment: The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Comment: When you get an error, search that error in google. There are so many solutions. for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007551/the-fastcgi-process-exited-unexpectedly

Comment: Hi David    I have done all tasks according to your given url but no solution yet.

Comment: C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Comment: Maybe post a new question with your new problem. But you should provide more information because this error just means something caused your php to crash. It could be anything.